# ES6 Proxies in Angular Template

Tags: angular, es6-proxy

I am using RxDB (essentially a wrapper for `pouchdb` using `rxjs`), in my Angular application.  Each document in the database (called an `RxDocument`) is a ES6 Proxy.  For instance, I could have and `RxDocument` like so:

```
 Object{
    arr : getter
    arr : setter
 }
```

However, when I try to reference this getter in an Angular template, it causes the browser tab to crash, as the NgZone freaks out.  For instance:

```
<div *ngFor="let arr of this.document.arr"></div>
```

How can I reference the proxied value in a way that doesn't upset the functionality of Angular change detection?